# Vaadin How to make the table header invisible

Tags: vaadin

I have a requirement where i need to display patients schedule details in tabular form.
But I should not display the table column headers instead I will have a panel with some navigation arrows and a date field where in i have display the patients data according to some navigation rules. And also each table row should expand when user selects a row displaying additional information about that pirticular patient.

Is it possible to display a table without table column headers, and with expandable table rows in Vaadin. I am quite new to vaadin so any help is greatly appreceated.

Regards
Ajay

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible to display a table without column headers.

Please use the method setColumnHeaderMode with Table.COLUMN_HEADER_MODE_HIDDEN as argument.

for example:

Table aTable=new Table();
...
aTable.setColumnHeaderMode(Table.COLUMN_HEADER_MODE_HIDDEN);

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. Now what about expandable table rows. This is crux of our application, does vaadin support expandable table rows?

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, if the above suggestion work? I don't think expandable table rows exist in Vaadin. Can you please elaborate more using an Example?

Comment: side note: `Table.COLUMN_HEADER_MODE_HIDDEN` is now deprecated and `ColumnHeaderMode.HIDDEN` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

CRH's answer is the right answer not to display table headers.

for expandable table you can use TreeTable component which you can find [here](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-treetable)